# Why are these sites cloning my content, and how do I stop them?

Tags: google-index, legal, search-results

So I was searching for one of my own websites on Google: `http://www.botlibre.com`

and to my surprise found some clones of my website, like:

`http://83waystowasteyourtime.adidas.com`

and:

`http:// mediaiq.astral.comm`

My question are:

1. Why are they creating clones of my website?  Some kind of SEO scheme or what? What gain could they be getting?
2. How do they have a URL at `adidas.com` and `astral.comm`?  I assume it's not Adidas steeling my content.
3. How do I shutdown these sites and stop people from stealing my content?
   (on Tomcat)

Comment: http://www.copyscape.com/  Seems to be a good resource for finding duplicated content, that's how I found some copies of my site.

Answer (score 17):

Okay. This is a rather odd one, but not as tragic as you would think.

I am not sure what the payoff would be. This makes absolutely no sense to me as to why someone would do this. I cannot see an advantage for the hacker at all. The good news is the visitor is reaching *your* site. However, there will be a hit from an SEO standpoint so you want to fix this fast.

Your site, I assume, is not on a shared server so if you access your site by the IP address, it will still work. I tested this and it does.

83waystowasteyourtime.adidas.com and mediaiq.astral.com are sub-domains using an old hack that allows anyone to create a sub-domain for any unsuspecting domain. You can read about it here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/watch-out-for-dns-sub-domain-hijacking/ There are more sites if you Google *subdomain dns hack*.

The good news is this. These are not clones or copies of your site, they ***are*** your site. Each sub-domain points to your IP address specifically.

You can do a:

```
> dig 83waystowasteyourtime.adidas.com any
```

and

```
> dig mediaiq.astral.comm any
```

on any linux computer to see.

You can likely combat this, though I am not sure what method will work:

Assuming you have Apache installed, you can edit your .htaccess file within your web root directory and insert the following code.

Add the following at the top of the file to turn on the rewrite engine.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Blocking by host:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^83waystowasteyourtime\.adidas\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

--or--

Blocking by referrer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^83waystowasteyourtime\.adidas\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

You will want to test these and tell us which one works. Please. It may be we need to fish around for another method.

Of course you can change the rewrite rule and redirect them to your site directly, with:

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.botlibre.com [R=301,L]
```

--or--

Send them to hell (humor) with:

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.hell.com [R=301,L]
```

...which is a real site. But you would passing the problem onto them.

**I recommend blocking them.**

As @Martijn mentioned in his comment and it is well worth preserving, you can have canonical links per page to help protect you. In this case, the link would point to the page the link is on. It is more work, but it seems like a good idea these days.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/booger-eating-tyrants" />
```

As well, you can reach the parent domain owners and let them join you in the battle:

Adidas.com

```
Admin Name: Albert Pedraz
Admin Organization: adidas AG
Admin Street: Adi-Dassler-Strasse 1
Admin City: Herzogenaurach
Admin State/Province:
Admin Postal Code: 91074
Admin Country: DE
Admin Phone: +49.9132844584
Admin Email: adidas@role.noris.net

Tech Name: noris.net Hostmaster
Tech Organization: noris network AG
Tech Street: Thomas-Mann-Str. 16-20
Tech City: Nuernberg
Tech State/Province:
Tech Postal Code: 90471
Tech Country: DE
Tech Phone: +49.91193520
Tech Fax: +49.9119352100
Tech Email: hostmaster@noris.net
```

Astral.com

```
Admin Name: Van Tu Duong
Admin Organization: Bell Media Inc.
Admin Street: 9 Channel Nine Court,
Admin City: Scarborough
Admin State/Province: Ontario
Admin Postal Code: M1S 4B5
Admin Country: CA
Admin Phone: +1.5148702477
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax:
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: trademarks@bell.ca

Tech Name: Van Tu Duong
Tech Organization: Bell Media Inc.
Tech Street: 9 Channel Nine Court,
Tech City: Scarborough
Tech State/Province: Ontario
Tech Postal Code: M1S 4B5
Tech Country: CA
Tech Phone: +1.5148702477
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax:
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: trademarks@bell.ca
```

Comment: And add a 301-header to your site, and add a canonicaltag to your pages so searchenigines knwo the original. Might as well take this to your advantage :)

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for the comment! I updated the answer with a canonical link example. This should help people in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the great info.  What file do I put "RewriteCond " in exactly?  Also any answer to question #1, why? what benefit are they getting from this?

Comment: @James I updated the answer. I did answer question 1, but it was lower in my answer and likely easily missed. I moved it to the top and expanded upon it somewhat. I also added what file and where to find it- assuming Apache (this is Apache code). I do not know IIS at all anymore. I has been well over a decade since I have done anything with IIS. Rememeber, I am not sure which set of code works, but I rather suspect that the %{HTTP_REFERER} version is correct. Please test and let us know what the results are. Again, assuming Apache.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Tomcat, any idea how to do this on Tomcat?

Comment: @James I am sorry that I do not know Tomcat. However, Tomcat uses a similar redirect method as Apache. The code should look similar or be the same. It is possible to configure Tomcat to use an .htaccess file, but I have not yet found any good information on this. However, here is the documentation for using mod_rewrite (the code I provided) on Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html I hope this helps. Hopefully/Perhaps there is a Tomcat user out there that can reply.